# Line up UIButton with the beginning of where the separator starts on a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I want a UIButton in my project to have an x-value of the beginning of where a UITableView's (placed below the UIButton) separators are.

```
[BUTTON]

********BOUNDS OF THE UITABLEVIEW********
   --------------------------------------
   [THESE LINES REPRESENT THE SEPARATORS]
   --------------------------------------
   [THESE LINES REPRESENT THE SEPARATORS]
   -------------------------------------- 
********BOUNDS OF THE UITABLEVIEW********
```

What I want it to look like is this, the frame of the UITableView is not the same as the insets of the separators.

```
   [BUTTON]

********BOUNDS OF THE UITABLEVIEW********
   --------------------------------------
   [THESE LINES REPRESENT THE SEPARATORS]
   --------------------------------------
   [THESE LINES REPRESENT THE SEPARATORS]
   -------------------------------------- 
********BOUNDS OF THE UITABLEVIEW********
```

And I want the calculation to be dynamic meaning that if say the orientation changes, the button will still be lined up correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `separatorInset` to determine the inset of the separator from the bounds of the row.